# check for a span class content and then update the quantity using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code code here:

```
//Check current
if (parseInt($("#Quantity").val()) < 25) {
// If it is less than 25 then set it to 25
$("#Quantity").attr("value", "25");
}
```

It checks if the quantity box has less than 25 and if it is, adds 25 to the box.
The problem is on a particular product i need to check IF my pages contains:

```
<span class="ProductNameText">This is product ABC</span>
```

This is a work around because the customer only has 2 products which dont require 25 quantity. Ideally i would want to check if a page contained Kit Option form fields and then add 25 to the box.

Any ideas on how to check for a span and then update the quantity. But the quantity shouldnt be forced, so if the user wants 6 items they should be able to add that figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if($('span.ProductNameText').text()=='This is product ABC'){
    //Check current 
  if (parseInt($("#Quantity").val()) < 25) { 
    // If it is less than 25 then set it to 25 
    $("#Quantity").attr("value", "25");
 }
}
```

hope i understood your query.

Comment: if it contains "something" then the user can select either 1-2000

Answer (score 0):

Try using `length`:

```
//Check current
if ($("#Quantity").val().length < 25) {
    // If it is less than 25 then set it to 25
    $("#Quantity").attr("value", "25");
}
```

Comment: thanks but how does this solve the issue of finding the product name from the span class?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if a span with class 'ProductNameText' exists you could do this  -

```
if (parseInt($("#Quantity").val()) < 25) && ($("span.ProductNameText").length > 0) {
// If it is less than 25 then set it to 25
 $("#Quantity").attr("value", "25");
}
```

If you wanted to check that the span contains specific text you could use the [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) -

```
if (parseInt($("#Quantity").val()) < 25) && ($("span.ProductNameText:contains('sometext')").length > 0)
```

If you want to check user edited contents based on whether the div exists you could use the `change` event -

```
$("#Quantity").change( function() {
   if ($("span.ProductNameText:contains('sometext')").length > 0) {
        // check input ($(this).val()) here
  }
  else // check for differnt input ($(this).val()) here wher span doe snot exist    
});
```

This will check the value of the text box once the text box loses focus, the logic can be switch depending on whether the span exists

Comment: thanks, i need to be able to insert a value less than 25 and more than 25 in the box if i find the span text. The user should be able to do this...